# BASH - Select All Code Between A Multiline Div

Tags: bash

I have a div on all of my eCommerce site's pages holding SEO content. I'd like to count the number of words in that div. It's for diagnosing empty pages in a large crawl.

The div always starts as follows:

```
<div class="box fct-seo fct-text
```

It then contains `<h1>`, `<p>` and `<a>` tags.

it then, obviously,  closes with `</div>`

How can I, using SED, AWK, WC, etc take all the code between the start of the div and its closing div and count how many words occur. If it's 90% accurate, I'm happy.

You'd somehow have to tell it to stop scanning before the first closing `</div>` it finds.

Here's an example page to work with:

http://www.zando.co.za/women/shoes/

Much appreciated.
-P

Answer (score 3):

When it gets more complicated (like divs nested with in that div) the regex approach [won't work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1501222) and you need a html parser, like in my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html). Then you can find the text

either with css:

```
xidel http://www.zando.co.za/women/shoes/  -e 'css(".fct-seo")' | wc -w
```

or pattern matching:

```
xidel http://www.zando.co.za/women/shoes/  -e '<div class="box fct-seo fct-text">{.}</div>' | wc -w
```

It will also only print the text, not the html tags. (if you/someone wanted them, you could add the --printed-node-format xml option)

Answer (score 1):

In a Perl one-liner you can use the `..` operator to specify the patterns that match the beginning and end of the region you're interested in:

```
$ perl -wne 'print if /<div class="box fct-seo fct-text/ .. /<\/div>/' shoes.html
```

You can then count the words with `wc -w`:

```
$ perl -wne 'print if /<div class="box fct-seo fct-text/ .. /<\/div>/' shoes.html | wc -w
```

If counting the ‘words’ in the HTML tags themselves is affecting the numbers enough to affect the accuracy, you can remove those from the count with something like:

```
$ perl -wne 'next unless /<div class="box fct-seo fct-text/ .. /<\/div>/; s/<.*?>//g; print' shoes.html | wc -w
```

Comment: Good answer. The final line in your answer does the job perfectly.Just another question, I'm trying to integrate your snippet in my BASH loop. I have a for loop with $i being the URL being scanned. How Can I feed that URL to your PERL line?

Comment: You need a command which downloads a webpage and emits its content on standard output. Do you have any of `GET`, `wget`, or `curl` available?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
grep -Pzo '(?<=<div)(.*?\n)*?.*?(?=</div)' -n inputFile.html | sed 's/^[^>]*>//'
```

Comment: Thanks anishsane, out of the myriad of greps I tried, to clean up pages of a long copy/paste from YouTube channel comments (the gdata api will only get 1 vid at a time, and page source does not show threaded comments), only your script did the trick. A lot for me to review and learn on this one. Thanks!